# is there any way to hyperlink text inside textview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking for hiperlink in single word in Textview.

```
txt.setText(Word1 + "\t" + Word2 + "\t" + word3);
```

Now I would like to add hyperlink in **word2**.

So is there anyway to set this text.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(Word1 + "<a href=\"your_link\">"+Word2+"</a>"));
```

To change the html in the onClickListener

I suggest you create your own class that extends TextView and add to it

```
String Word1;
String Word2;
```

In this way you can easily setText again and again without parsing the text

Anyway in the

> onClickListener

Use again

> setText

Comment: I would like to apply style and color eg. txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(Word1 + "<a href=\"Link\" style=text-decoration: none>"+Word2+"</a>"));

Comment: No. Once the change in html it set the text I mean I would like to apply my own color to display link without underline in textview.

Comment: I dont know if i am following you .. but do you mean that you want the link not to be underlined? This is done using CSS! a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover

Answer (score 0):

You can call any hyperlink with webview in onClickListner of a textview.